# Error al actualizar datos en view edit Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Cuando quiero editar un registro de mi sistema, al guardarlo me saltan advertencias de que ciertos campos son obligatorios pero dichos campos no los quiero editar.

¿Como puedo hacer para que no me haga esas advertencias en los campos que no quiero editar?

No puedo editar el FormRequest sacando los required, si lo hago me da otros errores.

Dejo una imagen de la incidencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui dejo la funcion correspondiente a update del controlador:

```
    public function update(PMedicamentosFormRequest $request,$id)
    {

        $pmedicamento=PMedicamentos::findOrFail($id);

        $pmedicamento->CI=$request->get('CI');
        $pmedicamento->Primer_Nombre=$request->get('Primer_Nombre');
        $pmedicamento->Primer_Apellido=$request->get('Primer_Apellido');
        $pmedicamento->Departamento=$request->get('Departamento');
        $pmedicamento->idmedicamento=$request->get('idmedicamento');
        $pmedicamento->idprestador=$request->get('idprestador');
        $pmedicamento->idlaboratorio=$request->get('idlaboratorio');
        $pmedicamento->N_Sentencia=$request->get('N_Sentencia');
        $pmedicamento->Fecha_Sentencia=$request->get('Fecha_Sentencia');
        $pmedicamento->Tipo_Solicitud=$request->get('Tipo_Solicitud');
        $pmedicamento->update();
        return Redirect::to('PMedicamentos');
    }
```

Aquí dejo el modelo utilizado:

```
namespace sisMSP;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PMedicamentos extends Model
{
    protected $table='pmedicamentos';

    protected $primaryKey='idpmed';

    public $timestamps=false;

    protected $fillable =[
         'idmedicamento',
         'idprestador',
         'idlaboratorio',
         'CI',
         'Primer_Nombre',
         'Primer_Apellido',
         'Departamento',
         'N_Sentencia',
         'Fecha_Sentencia',
         'Tipo_Solicitud',
         'Condicion'

    ];


    protected $guarded =[

    ];
```

Si es necesario que suba algo mas del codigo, solo diganme y lo subo.

Espero sus respuestas

Comment: ¿cuáles son esos errores que mencionas aparecen si quitas el `required` del `FormRequest`?

Comment: si quito solo el required, me salta error del sql, debo habilitar para que puedan ser nulos?

Comment: Si los campos son obligatorios a la hora de crear (no editar) un registro, entonces tu `FormRequest` está bien. El problema es porque no se están enviando esos campos al editar (porque en la imagen se ven completos). Estarán mal los nombres de los campos? Fijate en la consola de tu explorador que campos se están enviando al hacer click en `Guardar`.

Comment: Efectivamente, estaban mal los nombres de los campos enviados